# AnonymizeIp and an IP filter

Tags: google-analytics

We would like to enable anonymizeIp for our google analytics tracking (following the gdpr advice in our country). However we also have an IP filter (exclude) for certain IP addresses.

[On the google analytics support pages the following statement is made:](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2763052?hl=en)

> This feature is designed to help site owners comply with their own
>   privacy policies or, in some countries, recommendations from local
>   data protection authorities, which may prevent the storage of full IP
>   address information. The IP anonymization/masking takes place as soon
>   as data is received by the Analytics Collection Network, before any
>   storage or processing takes place.

This would mean the IP filter would not work anymore. Is there anyway to bypass this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have any other unique filter fields (i.e. you can convince all your users to have a unique user agent or something) there is no solution that uses purely GA.

You could capture the IP in your webpage (either on the server side or via javascript before the GA payload is send to the server) and then either not load the code or set a custom dimension that you use for filtering.

Or you are simply okay with removing a whole block -  IP anonymization sets the last tuple to zero, so an IP filter for 123.123.123.0 would remove all users from 123.123.123.0 to 123.123.123.255. If it does not bother you that you throw out 254 harmless addresses then that is the simples solution.

Comment: Be aware that there is a side effect of switching on anonymisation, in that it loses some of the detail of GA's geolocation information.

Comment: @MandyShaw, you are of course right, but us Europeans don't really have a choice on the matter (also the Google docs suggest that the effect should not be too bad).

Comment: I am in Europe too ... we're stuck between a rock and a hard place. I just wanted the OP to be clear in advance re that particular nasty little side-effect.